# Create a user-defined type with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I am trying to create a user defined type with Cassandra. I am using `cqlsh` and the example provided in the documentation (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlRefcreateType.html):

```
REATE TYPE address (
  street text,
  city text,
  zip_code int,
  phones set<text>
)
```

But this returns:

```
Bad Request: line 1:7 no viable alternative at input 'TYPE'
```

Using the `help` command, I found the 'CREATE_TABLE_TYPES' but I could not get it to work either.

What is the correcft syntax to get this to work?

Many thanks

Comment: Which Cassandra version are you using? User-types are part of 2.1 and later

Comment: ok I am using 2.0.11, my bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also struck with same problem. User type doesn't supported by earlier version of `2.1`.
Now i am using `2.1.2` version of `cassandra`.

You can find it [NEW FEATURES](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/features2.html) of Cassandra

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to create a keyspace first:

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE excelsior
   ...   WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };
cqlsh> use excelsior;
cqlsh:excelsior> CREATE TYPE address (
             ...   street text,
             ...   city text,
             ...   zip_code int,
             ...   phones set<text>
             ... );
```

Comment: That's not the case. He/she was using 2.0.x, which doesn't support user types;